# Change the value of a sql field when time reaches a specified date

Tags: php, sql

I have a website where you can register to it

Registered account's status is by default "Stand by", then the administrator of the website can change that status to either : "admin" - "user" - "stand by"

The expiring date is also stored in the database

What I want to do is, when the expiring date is reached, automatically change that user's status to "Stand by"

I have no idea on how to do this, thanks for any help !

Example :

[If we reach 2020 - 07 - 10, user4's (and also "test" and "testt") status should change to "Attente" (means Stand by)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcDpi.png)

My database :

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfa4T.png)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a view:

```
create view v_t as
    select . . .,
           (case when now() >= expiring_date then 'Stand by' else status end) as status
    from t;
```

This calculates the status when the view is *read*, so you don't have to worry about statuses changing.  The status is always correct.

Then, at your leisure, you can go an update the statuses in the data using a job.

With this approach, your applications are guaranteed to see the correct status.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean :( From what I read online, I need to create a cron job ?